# replace java loop with query in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I used postgresql 10 and spring boot

I try with success to load  tree using loop in java.

in the loop I call each time the query

but it consumes cpu in application server and cpu in database server and takes time to load the tree which contain 5000 unit.

I want using only  one query to load the tree without loop in java.
the result from java is `ResponseEntity<List<UnitDTO>>`

this is my code :

```
  @GetMapping("/unitsBook")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<UnitDTO>> getAllUnitsBook(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam(name="lang", required=false) String lang,
    @RequestParam(name="emp", required=false) String empID) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Units");
        Page<UnitDTO> page = unitService.findAllUnitBook(pageable, lang,empID);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/unitsBook");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

the java code which contains the loop is :

```
public List<UnitDTO> getUnitBookList(Pageable pageable, String lang,String empID) {

        List<UnitDTO> list=unitRepository.findUnitList(pageable, lang,empID);
        List<UnitDTO> unitChildList=getChildrenUnitList(list,lang,pageable,empID);

        return unitChildList;
 }

private List<UnitDTO> getChildrenUnitList(
        List<UnitDTO> unitList, String lang,Pageable pageable,String empID) {

     for(UnitDTO UnitDTO : unitList) {

         List<UnitDTO> childrenListEntity = unitRepository.findUnitByParentId(pageable, lang,UnitDTO.getValue(),empID);
         UnitDTO.setChildren(getChildrenUnitList(childrenListEntity,lang,pageable,empID));

     }

        return unitList;
    }
```

and the code which call query is :

```
  public List<UnitDTO> findUnitList(Pageable pageable, String lang,String empID) {
      
    String querystr = "SELECT ";
    querystr += " unl.name AS text ,";
    querystr += " un.id AS value ,";
    querystr += " ,cast( 0 as varchar(10) ) as favoriteNbr,cast( null as varchar(10) ) as favoriteId ";
    querystr += " FROM public.unit un ";
    querystr += " LEFT OUTER JOIN public.unitlang unl ON unl.unit_id = un.id ";
    querystr += " Where unl.lang = :lang  parentid is null  order by app_order asc";

    log.debug("-- Query:" + querystr);

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(querystr, "UnitDTOMap");
    query.setParameter("lang", lang);

    List<UnitDTO> unitDTOs = query.getResultList();

    if (pageable.isUnpaged()) {
      return unitDTOs;
    }

    return unitDTOs;
  }





  @Override
  public List<UnitDTO> findUnitByParentId(Pageable pageable, String lang, String idParent,String empID) {
    log.debug("-- pageable:" + pageable.getPageNumber() + ", Size:" + pageable.getPageSize() + ", isUnpaged:" + pageable.isUnpaged() + ", lang:" + lang);
    lang = lang.toUpperCase();
    String querystr = "SELECT ";

    querystr += " unl.name AS text ,";
    querystr += " un.id AS value ,"; 
    querystr += " (case when cast((select count(*) from employee where employee.unit_id = un.id) as varchar(10)) != '0'  then cast(1 as Boolean)  else cast(0 as BOOLEAN) end) as disabled";
    querystr += " ,cast( 0 as varchar(10) ) as favoriteNbr,cast( null as varchar(10) ) as favoriteId ";
    querystr += " FROM unit un ";
    querystr += " LEFT OUTER JOIN unitlang unl ON unl.unit_id = un.id ";
    querystr += " Where unl.lang = :lang  and un.parentid = :idParent order by app_order asc ";

    log.debug("-- Query:" + querystr);

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(querystr, "UnitBookDTOMap");
    query.setParameter("lang", lang);
    query.setParameter("idParent", idParent);
    List<UnitDTO> unitDTOs = query.getResultList();

    log.debug("-- unitDTOs Size:" + unitDTOs.size());

    if (pageable.isUnpaged()) {
      return unitDTOs;
    }

    return unitDTOs;
  }
```

**Updated :**

I try to use the recursive query but the problem is that the tree does not display correctly.
all the unit are in same level.
I think  the problem in this line WHERE id = :idParent I comment it because I didn't find how can I send it

```
  public List<UnitDTO> getUnitBookList(Pageable pageable, String lang) {
    
                List<UnitDTO> list=unitRepository.findUnitList(pageable, lang);
              //  List<UnitBookDTO> unitChildList=getChildrenUnitList(list,lang,pageable);
    
                return list;
         }
         
    
     @Override
      public List<UnitDTO> findUnitList(Pageable pageable, String lang) {
        log.debug("-- pageable:" + pageable.getPageNumber() + ", Size:" + pageable.getPageSize() + ", isUnpaged:" + pageable.isUnpaged() + ", lang:" + lang);
        lang = lang.toUpperCase();
        String querystr = "WITH RECURSIVE un_id AS ( ";
    
        querystr += " SELECT id";
        querystr += "  FROM unit ";
  //  querystr += " WHERE id = :idParent";
    querystr += " UNION";
        querystr += " SELECT unit.id";
   
        querystr += " FROM unit JOIN un_id ON unit.parentid = un_id.id )  ";
        querystr += " SELECT unl.name                          AS text, un.id                             AS value, (case   when cast((select count(*) from employee where employee.unit_id = un.id) as varchar(10)) != '0' ";
        querystr += " then cast(1 as Boolean)   else cast(0 as BOOLEAN) end) as disabled , cast(0 as varchar(10))            as favoriteNbr,";
        querystr += " cast(null as varchar(10))         as favoriteId FROM un_id JOIN unit un USING (id) LEFT OUTER JOIN unitlang unl ON unl.unit_id = un.id Where unl.lang = :lang order by app_order asc";
    
        log.debug("-- Query:" + querystr);
    
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(querystr, "UnitDTOMap");
        query.setParameter("lang", lang);
    
        List<UnitDTO> unitDTOs = query.getResultList();
    
        log.debug("-- unitDTOs Size:" + unitDTOs.size());
    
        if (pageable.isUnpaged()) {
          return unitDTOs;
        }
    
        return unitDTOs;
      }
```

Comment: You could add the `parentid` to the column list and then build the tree in Java. What is the problem with the `:idParent`? You'd need to pass it like `query.setParameter("idParent", empID);`.

Comment: I use two methods findUnitLis and getChildrenUnitList.

empID is not related to idParent,  and also not used in findUnitLis.

the idParent parameter is used in findUnitByParentId which is called by the second method : getChildrenUnitList   and now is commented in my code

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to fetch a tree in SQL is to use a recursive [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE un_id AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM unit
    WHERE id = :idParent -- or parentid if you want to exclude the parent itself

    UNION

    SELECT unit.id
    FROM unit
    JOIN un_id
        ON unit.parentid = un_id.id
)
SELECT unl.name                          AS text,
       un.id                             AS value,
       (case
            when cast((select count(*) from employee where employee.unit_id = un.id) as varchar(10)) != '0'
                then cast(1 as Boolean)
            else cast(0 as BOOLEAN) end) as disabled
        ,
       cast(0 as varchar(10))            as favoriteNbr,
       cast(null as varchar(10))         as favoriteId
FROM un_id -- reference to the CTE
JOIN unit un
    USING (id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN unitlang unl ON unl.unit_id = un.id
Where unl.lang = :lang
order by app_order asc
```

Recursively fetch all the IDs and then join the rest of the needed data.

Comment: thank you for the response,I have update my question. I try to use the recursive query but the problem is that the tree does not display correctly. all the unit are in same level